# dividing single column into two columns

Tags: html, css

How can I divide the payment column into refund and transfer fee on the bases of comments column?

```html
<table>
<thead>
  <th>Payment</th>
  <th>comments</th>
  
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
   <td>3000</td>
    <td>refund</td>
      </tr>
    
    <tr>
   <td>3000</td>
    <td>refund</td>
      </tr>
    
    <tr>
   <td>3000</td>
    <td>transfer fee</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
  
</table>
```

Comment: Very Unclear Question. Can you please post your desired output?

Comment: output should be in form like   payment =6000 where comments='refund' and payment=3000 where comments='transfer fee'

Comment: Nothing to do whit PHP

Comment: how could i select and sum the records in php

Comment: @SafdarPathan - Post your code

Comment: i havnt write any code for this yet i m asking about the phpmysql query for such selection

Comment: how to retrieve same column twice with different conditions in same table

Answer (score 0):

Write your query as below:-

```
SELECT payment AS PAYMENT,comments AS COMMENTS FROM TableName 
WHERE comments = 'refund' OR comments = 'transfer fee'
```

Comment: Ravi Hirani thanks for responce but it just select the rows .i want to sum up the payment separatly for both comments (refund AND transfer fee)

Comment: how to retrieve same column twice with different conditions in same table

Answer (score 0):

you may have to try something like this:-

```
SELECT SUM(fund), SUM(refund) FROM
    (
    SELECT
    payment, comments ,
    CASE  when (comments !='transfer fee'  )   then payment else '' end  As fund,
    CASE     when (comments !='refund'  )   then payment else '' end  As refund,
    FROM `tblname` ) tbl
WHERE tbl.comments = 'refund' OR tbl.comments = 'transfer fee'
```

the inner query is using same column for fund and refund using [CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html)

```
SELECT
    payment, comments ,
    CASE  when (comments !='transfer fee'  )   then payment else '' end  As fund,
    CASE     when (comments !='refund'  )   then payment else '' end  As refund,
    FROM `tblname`
```